# Capistrano DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories) .git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano, digital-ocean

I have an app that i am working on that i did not set up and i don't have communication with the dev's that did. I have pushed up to it in the past but today for some reason i was not able to. Rails 4 with capistrano. When i looked at the app directory on the server i could find the `.gitignore` but no `.git` folder. I did a "`git init && git remote add git_ssh_url`" but it didn't work. I was thinking about a git clone but i have no clue what that will do to the app. The app is used daily at a company and i'm sure they wouldn't like me screwing it up :)  I'm at a loss, Any help is appreciated.

**

- Edit

**
So i realized that there is a staging server set up on the same droplet as well and the code to deploy to each is nearly identical. I had no problems updating the staging server

Here is the error code:

```
refreshing local cache to revision 4ea064e4826a9880c6bac3e0a2689b688e223911 at /var/folders/qb/6fdgzljs1r9ddgkvqk1ky0y40000gn/T/mpm
        executing locally: cd /var/folders/qb/6fdgzljs1r9ddgkvqk1ky0y40000gn/T/mpm && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 4ea064e4826a9880c6bac3e0a2689b688e223911 && git clean -q -d -x -f
    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
        command finished in 9ms
    shell command failed with return code pid 97172 exit 128
```

Comment: Try to re-initialize repository locally by git init command. Check for the directory .git which will be in hidden mode default .

Comment: Thanks @Prasad but there wasn't a hidden repo anywhere i could find. I did do a git init but since there is no .git directory it's just creating a blank new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution i came across while asking a friend was that somehow the temp cache file that capistrano creates locally here (this path was pulled form the error that i posted above) :

> /var/folders/qb/6fdgzljs1r9ddgkvqk1ky0y40000gn/T/mpm

was throwing the error. At some point there must have been an interrupted deploy that messed up that file. When i ls -la the mpm file above there was a .git file but for whatever reason it wasn't recognized.

The solution was to

> rm -rf /var/folders/qb/6fdgzljs1r9ddgkvqk1ky0y40000gn/T/mpm

and rerun the cap production deploy command and it rebuilds the temp cache file and deploys the code.

Hope this helps someone!